# Swift 4 - Update variable in UIPageViewController in its UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIPageViewController` with 5 `UIViewController` inside it. In my `UIPageViewController` I have an object defined.

```
var patient = PatientsRegisterClass()

lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PatientsUserController") as! PatientsUserController,
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PatientsLocationController") as! PatientsLocationController,
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PatientsPainController") as! PatientsPainController,
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PatientsPainkillersController") as! PatientsPainkillersController,
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PatientsPainStoryController") as! PatientsPainStoryController,

    ]
}()
```

My question is how do I pass this object when I goto the next view controller so I can update the object. Here is how I am getting to the next and previous view controller

```
 func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

    guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]

}
```

Here is my object

```
class PatientsRegisterClass: NSObject {

var user_name = String()

var email = String()

var password = String()

var fkcountry = Int()

var fkregion = Int()

var fkcity = Int()

var address = String()

var fkpaintype = String()

var fkpainlevel = String()

var patient_painyears = Int()

var usage_painkillers = Bool()

var painkiller = Int()

var other_painkiller = String()

var is_public = Bool()

var patient_painstory = String()

var patient_image = String()

}
```

Comment: Do you want to access patient variable from PatientsUserController, PatientsLocationController, PatientsPainController, etc?

Comment: Yes...I want to define patient in the UIPageViewController and access it in the my View Controllers (PatientsUserController, PatientsLocationController, PatientsPainController)

Answer (score 0):

Set yourself as the page view controller’s delegate and implement this method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdelegate/1614091-pageviewcontroller

You know the current child (page), and this method tells you the incoming child, and thus you can configure the incoming child as desired.

Comment: In this delegate method we can pass data from page view controller to another view controller. What if we want to update the value in view controller 1 and use updated value in another view controller? We can use custom delegate or closure to update it. But why static var isn't correct?

Comment: I don’t know about the static var apart from its being a bad smell, but “You can't access the PageViewController and it's properties from the view controllers” is simply false.

Comment: And as I said in my answer, the delegate method is the moment when you know _two_ pages, the old one and the new one.

Comment: _"You can't access the PageViewController and it's properties from the view controllers"_ I meant, when a view controller is embedded in a navigation controller or tab bar controller, we can access directly as `self.navigationController` or `self.tabBarController`. While using page view controller, we can't get page view controller like this.

Comment: Well, that’s false. It is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621362-parent.